# .htaccess: 301 redirect "instr" url parameter to path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Via .htaccess **I want to 301 redirect a parameter "pathval" in an URL to a "path"**, e.g.:

```
index.php?a=1&b=2&pathval=a_text_string&c=3
```

to:

```
index.php/a_text_string
```

or even better to:

```
index.php/a_text_string?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

**I found many solutions for this redirect if "pathval" was the only URL parameter**.

But I did not manage to get it's value when there are **other parameters involved** in the QUERY_STRING and **all parameters could be in any order** and **may contain any value**.

So possible calls **(1)** which are to be directed may be:

- index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3  (here would be no redirection)
- index.php?pathval=a_text_string
- index.php?pathval=a_text_string&a=1&b=2&c=3
- index.php?a=1&b=2&pathval=a_text_string&c=3
- index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&pathval=a_text_string

I would be glad if someone could give me a general solution for all thinkable cases.

**(1)**: in my examples for better visibility the other parameters a,b,c are all numeric but this is not a rule. The also may contain strings or be even empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic rule for all the cases described in your question:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?pathval=([^&]*)&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}/%2?%1%3 [R=302,NE,L]
```

To remove `&&` or leading/trailing `&` use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&|&&|&$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&?(.*?)(?:&&(.*))?&?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer. In my tests it seems to work very good. The only thing I found is that it seems to leave the "&" after the pathval in: so `index.php?a=1&pathval=a_text_string&b=2` would lead to `index.php/a_text_string?a=1&&b=2` and  `index.php?pathval=a_text_string&a=1&b=2` to `index.php/a_text_string?&a=1&b=2`. Is there a way to remove this as well?

Comment: @Wooz Use `pathval=([^&]*)&?(\S*)\sHTTP`

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92 (added it to my answer)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Works perfectly now.